# Calling a local method inside a class in Node.js and module.export

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, es6-class

So I have a class with functions where one is dependent on another. This class is exported with module. According to anything I can find I should be able to use "this" but that throws an error.

Example:

```
class Test{

  test(){
    console.log('hello');
  }

  dependentMethod(){
    this.test();
  }
}

module.exports = Test;
```

This however throws these errors in node:

```
(node:69278) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
(node:69278) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:69278) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

It will work fine if I put the function outside the class though. Can anyone explain why this fails? :)

EDIT:

This is the code in server.js (simplified for the example) that uses the class:

```
const test = require(__dirname + '/server/Test');


const validator = async function(req, res, next){

    const test = new test();
    const serverTest = await test.dependentMethod();
    next();

};

app.get('/Response/:id/:is/:userId/:hash', validator, async function (req, res, next) {
   //does smth
}
```

Used seperately does not work either

```
const test = new Test();

app.get('/Response/:id/:is/:userId/:hash', Test.dependentMethod, async function (req, res, next) {
     //Same error
}
```

Comment: How do you import and use the module?

Comment: Please show the promise code that causes the rejection. The class itself is fine.

Comment: remove () next to class Test

Comment: Removed it. The original doesnt have it either

Comment: `const test = new test();` should throw a TDZ reference error - you need to use different names

Comment: `Test.dependentMethod`  is undefined. Did you mean `test.dependentMethod`? Please show the actual code. In any case, to pass a method as a callback [you need to bind it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Answer (score 5):

Working as expected.

Take a look here. You just need to rectify some syntactic errors.

**Test.js**

```
class Test{

  test(){
    console.log('hello');
  }

  dependentMethod(){
    this.test();
  }
}

module.exports = Test;
```

**Test1.js**

```
const fileR = require('./Test.js');

const validator = async function(){

 const fr = new fileR();
 const serverTest = await fr.dependentMethod();

};

validator();
```

**Output:**

```
> hello
```

Comment: Remove parenthesis while declaring a class. eg. `class Test`.

Comment: It does not work here, I use it as middleman for my get. Could there be something there?

Comment: Your `Test` class file contains `module.export` instead of `module.exports`, maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: @NicklasN, as described `sander` mentioned, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: This is a mistake, the original code has exports. And it works without the local call

Comment: Just set it up exactly like this, but it just throws the same error.

Comment: still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined` error should not come now? You might have some different issue, which may be not in this question.

Comment: Same error IF the function is INSIDE the class. If I put the function OUTSIDE of the class scope but in the same file it works fine

Comment: aah, maybe because you are not creating object correct. check this. `const test = require(__dirname + '/server/Test');` and you are initializing wrong `const test = new Test();` .... What you should do is, `const Test = require(__dirname + '/server/Test');` and then `const test = new Test();` will work. Take care about the capitalization of  `Test` and `test` both are different.

Comment: This is also done correct in my version, sorry. Lots of mistakes cause I typed it manually on here. The object gets invoked correctly

Comment: As the answer above suggests its something about the middleware usage

Comment: Can't help until your actual code. Seems mysterious to me now :(

Answer (score 2):

```
 class Test{

   test(){
    console.log('hello');
   }

   let dependentMethod = ()=>{
     this.test();
   }
  }

 module.exports = Test;
```

either manually bind this or use arrow functions which will bind `this` to the class object

Comment: Simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Man, you're not showing you real code to us.

I feel that in real life you are using `test.dependentMethod` as middleware. And it aclually is using standalone function loosing the context. Thats's why you have an error `Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`.

The solution is either using `test.dependentMethod.bind(test)` or the code from your *Edit* section, where you created separate validator function and using class instances correctly.

Comment: It is indeed the middleware part doing something weird. I cannot call it like the way you prescribe. It says test is undefined still